# Plane wave and polarisation

Tags: polarization, plane-wave

I am trying to understand the concept of a polarisation of a plane wave. Generally, the plane wave can be seen as a sum of two orthogonal linearly polarized waves. according to Wikipedia.

So I have started with a solution of a wave equation. $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two polarized waves, and the $E=E_1+E_2$ I have gotten as a linear polarized wave.

What is the the sum of these two waves? Will be it circular polar. wave too?

Comment: I see answers but what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf E_{\rm x} = E_{\rm x} \exp [i(kz-\omega t)]\hat x$ and $\mathbf E_{\rm y} = E_{\rm y} [i\exp (kz-\omega t+ \phi)]\hat y$

If $\phi = 0 \text{ or } \pi$ then $\mathbf E_{\rm x}+\mathbf E_{\rm y}$ wil give you a linearly polarised wave.

If $\phi $ has an arbitrary value then you get an elliptically polarised wave unless $E_{\rm x} =E_{\rm y}$ and $\phi = \pm \frac \pi 2$ when you will get circularly polarised light.

Adding the two circularly polarised waves of opposite sense and having the same amplitude will give you a linear polarised wave.

**Update** as a result of a comment by @LenaPark

Perhaps a phasor approach will help?

Here is an [animation from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_polarization) showing a rotating electric vector which is the essence of circularly polarised light.
It is the addition of two equal amplitude electric field which oscillate at right angles to one another and have a phase difference of $\frac \pi 2$.

[image]

Now see what happens if one adds another circularly polarised wave of the opposite sense.
This is a pictures of the electric vectors at one instant of time.

[image]

You will note that the y-components, $E_{\rm y1} \rm \,\text{and}\, E_{\rm y2}$ cancel each other out leaving just the x-components $E_{\rm x1} \rm \,\text{and}\, E_{\rm x2}$ adding together.
The result is a horizontal plane polarised wave.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the phase "arbitrary plane wave" implies a plane wave propagating in an arbitrary direction with an arbitrary state of polarization. Well, one can only produce such an arbitrary plane wave from the superposition of two orthogonal linearly (or circularly) polarized plane waves if the latter two are propagating in the same arbitrary direction. In other words, I cannot modify the direction of propagation simply by a superposition of plane waves. This is because they form a linearly independent (in fact orthogonal) set of functions.

Let's assume then that we fix the direction of propagation of the two orthogonally polarized plane waves and call that the $z$-direction. The linear combination will again be propagating in the $z$-drection. The question then is whether one can form an arbitray state of polarization. The answer is yes. All the possible states of polarization is given by the points on the surface of the [Poincare sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)). Such points are parameterized by two angles ($\theta,\phi$). Now it turns out that one can form any state of polarization by a linear combination
$$ \hat{n} = \alpha \hat{n}_1 + \beta \hat{n}_2 , $$ 
where the set $\{\hat{n}_1,\hat{n}_2\}$ is any set of two mutually orthogonal polarization vectors (such as left- and right-circular polarization); and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex-valued coefficients such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$. Explicit expressions in terms of ($\theta,\phi$) that would give such coefficients are
$$ \alpha(\theta,\phi) = \cos(\theta/2)\exp(i\phi/2) $$
$$ \beta(\theta,\phi) = \sin(\theta/2)\exp(-i\phi/2) . $$
You can check that one can generate all possible states of polarization with this formulation.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding of terms. A plane wave is defined as having infinite parallel and constant wavefronts. A wavefront is the surface containing all points at a fixed phase, $\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x} = const$. A plane wave can have arbitrary polarisation as long as it does not change perpendicular to the direction of propagation.

Mathematically this can be described by
$$\vec{E}(\vec{x},t) = \vec{E_0} \, e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x} - \omega t}$$
The physical field in this representation is just the real part of the expression. For a wave propagating into $z$-direction $\vec{E_0}=(|E_{0x}| \, e^{i\varphi_x}, |E_{0y}| \, e^{i\varphi_y}, 0)$ is the complex polarisation vector. Depending of the relative phase and magnitude of its components the wave has either linear, circular or elliptical.

For a linear polarised wave $|E_{0x}|=|E_{0y}|$ and $\varphi_y-\varphi_x=\delta= 0$ or $\delta=\pm \pi$. For a circular polarised wave $|E_{0x}|=|E_{0y}|$ and $\varphi_y-\varphi_x=\delta=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. Everything else is elliptical.

To get a linear polarisation as a superposition of two circular polarised waves, you have to add them in order to obtain a relative phase $\delta \in \{0,-\pi,\pi\}$. In general this means given two polarisations of

$$\vec{E}_{c1}=E_{c1} \, (e^{i \varphi_{c1}}, e^{i (\varphi_{c1} + \Delta_1)},0)$$
$$\vec{E}_{c2}=E_{c2} \, (e^{i \varphi_{c2}}, e^{i (\varphi_{c2} + \Delta_2)},0)$$

with $\Delta_1,\Delta_2 \in {-\pi/2,\pi/2}$, we need to find a

$$\vec{E}=\vec{E}_{c1}+\vec{E}_{c2}\stackrel{!}{=}E \, (e^{i \varphi}, e^{i (\varphi + \delta)},0).$$

This is a bit cumbersome. However, a trivial solution is given by a superposition of a left and a right circular polarised wave with equal magnitudes (amplitudes). In this case we have, for $\varphi_{c1}=\varphi_{c2}=0$,

$$\vec{E}_{c1}+\vec{E}_{c2} = E \, (1, e^{i\pi/2} + e^{-i\pi/2},0)=E \, (1, 0,0),$$
with $E=2 E_{c1}=2 E_{c2}$.

*edit: Trying to answer the question clarified in the comment*.